# Connection between sine and arctangent functions

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I've been reading a bit on some more advanced integration techniques, Fourier series, etc. and have noticed that sine and arctangent tend to appear together a lot in famous problems.

For example, when finding the Fourier series of a square wave,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      -1 & x\in(-\pi,0)\\
      1 & x\in(0,\pi)
   \end{cases}
$$

We find that

$$F(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\left(\sin(x)+\frac{1}{3}\sin(3x)+\frac{1}{5}\sin(5x)+\cdots\right)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left((2k-1)x\right)}{2k-1}$$

$F(\pi/2)$ upon rearrangement gives the Madhava-Leibniz Series for $\pi$:

$$\pi=4\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots\right)$$

However, a much easier way of obtaining this result is via the arctangent Taylor Series:

$$\text{atan}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}$$

Letting $x=\pi/4$ yields the same formula for $\pi$ as above.

$$\pi=4\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots\right)$$

---

We see another connection with the evaluation of the sine integral over $(0,\infty)$. Using the following property:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\mathcal L[f(x)]ds$$

Applying to the sine integral yields

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{ds}{s^2+1}=\left.\text{atan}(s)\right\rvert_0^\infty=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Namely, that the derivative of arctangent is the Laplace Transform of sine.

---

Is there some deeper reason these functions often seem to pop up in similar places, or am I merely grasping at straws, connecting dots that aren't there to begin with?